# Comparing 2 table data and printing all columns of 2 nd table data using java

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in sql server. And my objective is to compare 1st table column (TCODES) with 2 nd table column name (ST_Description ).If match found the pick rest all columns data in 2 nd table.I am able to get all data in console.But further i am not able to proceed.Your earliest response will help me.

1st table data in DB:

```
#TCODES(column name)#
  [SAT,
 ZN4963_PROM_01,
 /LCLCDP/BVOUTPUT,
 /LCLCDP/CSV_IDOC_CRE,
 /lclcdp/export_settl,
 /lclcdp/itemization,
 /lclcdp/TUD,
 /LCLCDP/UPLOAD_CSV,
 /N/LCLCDP/CSV_IDOC_CRE,
 /n/posdw/mon0 ,
 /posdw/mon0,
 AL11,
 ARCU_COIT1,
 AS01,
 AS02,
```

2nd table data in DB:Column names are release name

```
#Release_Name#      ##Cycle_Name##                 ###ST_DESCRIPTION ###
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oct Release         |SAP Regression 
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Navigate to SAT Inquiry page
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Navigate ARCU_COIT1 inuiry page
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Type ASN  pertaining to the PO
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Select AS01 option in UI
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Enter the dock  and click next
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Type  AL11 number ad qty in the 
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    | /lclcdp/itemization
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Navigate to ASN Inquiry page
February Release    |Non SAP - SIT - Feb2016    |Validate the /posdw/mon0
```

Comment: Create `join` query and compare `where table1.TCODES=table2.ST_Description`

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: bshivram already elaborate it...

Comment: my objective is to achieve it through java programming.

Answer (score 0):

First [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) the two tables by the common unique column, then use [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause to map your condition.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
JOIN ON TABEL1.ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE TABLE1.TCODES = TABLE2.ST_DESCRIPTION
```